# Customize menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, menu, customization, elementor

I want my main menu to be sorted rtl when I change the language without changing the main sort, which means the first element in the ltr design be the same one in rtl design.... if i move the element from menu customize when i use a mobile phone (drop-down menu ), the menu starts by the end .. i need help

I tried to reorder the item from appearance> menus .. but i want the same element which is in the first element  order in the ltr design to be the same first one in the rtl design.. cause i want to make my website multilingual.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming